# I'm trying to subtract a random number from 301 while looping until it gets to 0. Im using java

Tags: java, loops

This is what im working with right now. this generates a random number between 1 and 20 which is what i need. I'm just unsure how to incorporate this into a loop all the while subtracting from 301.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Project3{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int i;
    Random t = new Random();
    for (i = 1; i <= 1; i++){
      System.out.println(t.nextInt(20));

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This code will run once... That doesn't subtract anything at all either... For better help sooner show some more effort..

Comment: so, just define anther varialble `int num = 301` and do your substraction inside the loop lilke `num - t.nextInt(20);` Also, you need to change your loop condition to smth like `num > 0`

Comment: That code generates random numbers between 0 and 19, not between 1 and 20.

Comment: @SergeiSirik This is not a chat site, please spell out your words. Is it too much work to spell out "something", which is what I assume "smth" is supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

Try something along these lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  int i = 301;
  Random rand = new Random();
  while(i > 0) {
    i -= rand.nextInt(19) + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: That subtracts a number between 0 and 19, not between 1 and 20.